# VS2010 sp1 installation error "The feature is on a network resource that is unavailable"

Tags: visual-studio, silverlight, wcf-ria-services

I encountered  this error when i was installing the vs2010 sp1:
"The feature you are trying to use is on a network resource that is unavailable." 
the error comes out when installing the WCF RIA Services Sp1.
Is there anyone encountered the same error before?

Comment: This question would be better suited to [SuperUser](http://www.superuser.com)

Answer (score 7):

1) Download RiaServices.msi from http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=14880

2) Place RiaServices.msi file in the installation directory (example: C:\Users\%UserName%\AppData\Local\Temp\Microsoft Visual Studio 2010 Service Pack 1_10.0.40219)

3) Try a new installaton.